# Angular - How to disable Menu Item dynamically?

Tags: angular

I struggle to get a menu component running. I want to be able to disable a menu item, but i also don't want to have to much menu logic in the caller/user of the menu (here app-component).

So a refresh or something would not be so nice i think?

I am using onPush in the menu component but i don't think thats a problem. Even Using immutable menu items in the app component wouldn't help i think. The creation of the items in the constructor is the problem i think, but i don't know how to do it better.

A complicated way in the app componeent wouldn't be nice because the menu is used from menu components in this way.

Maybe a automatic refresh of the item(s) after a on() call could be the solution? But how?

Or should i create an observable/subject isDisabled$ and whenever the defined valued in that subject (app properties) i need to trigger the ChangeDetection?

Or do i need to make an Observable out of the menuItems and give them via async pipe to the menuItem?

Anybody some tipps? (In best case a good Best Practice :D )

Or is there a special CDK way to do it? I know there is a disabled directive but i think i would have the same problem as with the menu-item.disabled property

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-disable-fn6bj5?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

looking at how you designed your menu component using href `<a>` you'll have to use styles to disable items. just add an `ngClass` attribute to each item with the `disabled` predicate in order to do this.

the template should contain something like:

```
<a *ngIf="node.on" (click)="node.on()" [ngClass]="{'disabled-item':node.disabled()}"> {{node.name}} </a>
```

and the style should contain:

```
.disabled-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

by disabling the `pointer-events` you will get the result you wanted.

Comment: Thx for your hint for a version to disable it with css!
But i don't want to have the item in the template (see that item 2 is not in the list).
There has to be an option to keep the list clean with only the enabled items